# Speeding up datetime comparison with Cython

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I am trying to speed up comparison between datetimes using Cython, when passed a numpy array of datetimes (or details sufficient to create datetimes). To start, I tried to see how Cython would speed up comparison between integers.

```
testArrayInt = np.load("testArray.npy")
```

Python Method:

```
def processInt(array):
    compareSuccess = 0#number that is greater than
    testValue = 1#value to compare against
    for counter in range(testArrayInt.shape[0]):
        if testValue > testArrayInt[counter]:
            compareSuccess+=1
    print compareSuccess
```

Cython Method:

```
def processInt(np.ndarray[np.int_t,ndim=1] array):
    cdef int rows = array.shape[0]
    cdef int counter = 0
    cdef int compareSuccess = 0
    for counter in range(rows):
        if testInt > array[counter]:
            compareSuccess = compareSuccess+1
    print compareSuccess
```

Time Comparison with a numpy array of rows 1000000 is:

```
Python: 0.204969 seconds
Cython: 0.000826 seconds
Speedup: 250 times approx.
```

Repeating the same exercise with datetimes:
Since cython wouldnt accept an array of datetime, I split and sent an array of year, month and days to both the methods.

```
testArrayDateTime = np.load("testArrayDateTime.npy")
```

Python Code:

```
def processDateTime(array):
    compareSuccess = 0
    d = datetime(2009,1,1)#test datetime used to compare
    rows = array.shape[0]
    for counter in range(rows):
        dTest = datetime(array[counter][0],array[counter][1],array[counter][2])
        if d>dTest:
            compareSuccess+=1
    print compareSuccess
```

Cython Code:

```
from cpython.datetime cimport date

def processDateTime(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=2] array):
    cdef int compareSuccess = 0
    cdef int rows = avlDates.shape[0]
    cdef int counter = 0
    for counter in range(rows):
        dTest = date(array[counter,0],array[counter,1],array[counter,2])
        if dTest>d:
            compareSuccess=compareSuccess+1
    print compareSuccess
```

Performance:

```
Python: 0.865261 seconds
Cython: 0.162297 seconds
Speedup: 5 times approx.
```

Why is the speedup so low? And what is a possible way to increase this?

Comment: Are you familiar with `np.datetime64`?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, based on the cython docs which said "For every type in the numpy module there's a corresponding compile-time
type with a _t-suffix", I initially created my cython method as 

def processDateTime(np.ndarray[np.datetime64_t, ndim=2] testArray)

which gave me Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError. Hence i passed an array with year, month and day.

Comment: `np.datetime64` is an int64 under the hood, so you can pass into your cython function as `array.view('int64')`

Comment: @chrisb : So i tried that as per your suggestion but the result is a decrease by 0.001 seconds, having almost no effect on the speedup as i still have to create the date object on the Cython side.

Comment: The point would be to not create a date object, if all you need is a greater than, you can directly compare the ints (as they are ordinals).

Comment: is there a python variable among `if dTest>d:` ? Agreed that when using Cython you should avoid using any python object/library

Comment: Please provide samples (link to such tested files) for `testArrayDateTime.npy` and `testArray.npy` to test and investigate.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `date` object for every line. This takes more time, both because you have to allocate and deallocate memory and because it runs various checks on the arguments to ensure that it is a valid date.

For a faster comparison, either compare the `np.datetime64` array using integer comparison or compare the year, month and day columns separately as integers.